# How do you find the number of users that have disabled JavaScript in the browser?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get a count of number of user has disable javascript in browser. as google analytics code run on JS so i am not getting any count of nonJS user

Is there any tool or any site ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install something server-side to see how many unique visitors you are serving to.

Then you compare this number to the Google Analytics numbers to see how many of them have JavaScript disabled.

Comment: i have non costomised CMS where we can't write any server side code sorry i forget to mention that

Comment: @mikul: You should be able to analyze your web server logs to find out how many requests you have for the page containing the analytics code, though. Assuming that page is non-cacheable. FYI, globally, [about 2%](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/10/how-many-users-have-javascript-disabled/) of people have JavaScript disabled (or use a browser that just doesn't have it).

Comment: You could add a small image somewhere on your page that exists for no purpose except to track how many times it has been loaded (if you can get that info, maybe host it on Amazon S3 or some place with metrics). You can use that to approximate the total number of visits, but its not the most reliable thing in the world.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Yahoo's [How many users have JavaScript disabled?](https://web.archive.org/web/20121219004949/http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/10/how-many-users-have-javascript-disabled/), which documents a methodology.

Basically you can have a `<noscript>` tag, and some kind of counter in that tag (e.g. an image, or better an online non-JavaScript counter service). It will only be loaded (accessed) for the browsers which are not running browsers. However counting the image hits (in your access log) will give you hits with JS disabled, rather than unique visitors—if you use an online non-JavaScript counter service, this is likely to give you unique visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Google provides solutions for: PHP, JSP, ASP.NET, and Perl. 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/other/mobileWebsites

All solutions generate `<img>` tag.
Source code is provided, so you can port to any other language.